# Cannot delete Linux made files in Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7

My hard disk is divided into 3 partitions :

1. C:/ windows 7 partition
2. D:/ shared data partition
3. Ubuntu partition ( invisible in windows )

I have created some screenshots in Ubuntu and stored them in "Screenshots" folder in D:/ .

Now, I want to delete "Screenshots" folder using Windows but I can't.

I tried to delete it using cmd ( run as administrator ) and I got errors

[image]

Is that related to system files concept ( ext4 versus ntfs ) ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that ":" is an illegal character in a file name in Windows.
You should rename the files using Linux from Ubuntu partition or from a LiveCD.
I do not have Windows now, so I cannot replicate your situation to test this idea, but you can also try with 8.3 file names.
You can get them with dir /x command.
There are probably more solutions online, I just wanted to help you understand what can be causing your problem.

Comment: Is there a solution in windows platform ?

Comment: Try something like this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320081, specifically Cause 6.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting the error is because of the `:` character in the filenames. You can verify that by trying to create new file with any of the following characters, it will complain that the characters are not allowed. Linux allows use of these character in filenames.

`\ / : * ? " < > |`

The reason why `:` is not allowed is because Windows use colon character to determine the mount point \ drive. Read [Reserved characters and words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) and at [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions) for more details.

For example consider `C:\` so here as you can see the colon is used.

**EDIT:** You cannot perform any operation on those files in Windows, to solve the problem boot in ubuntu rename the files and now you are allowed to perform any operation on the files in windows. ***There is noting to do with permission here nor file system.***

Comment: I am not even allowed to rename these files

Answer (score 0):

you can use use
RD /S /Q "D:\Screenshots"